# ElasticSearch date format to get last Sunday

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I know for ES `now` means today

Is there any way to get last Sunday using some combination of `now`?

Context: We use Kibana and want to create a dashboard with a filter such that everyday it shows data for date ranges from last Sunday to today.

Comment: I don't think it exist. You do have [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-math-expressions.html#date-math-expressions) but it does not allow to reference date using then name of a day.

Comment: Please check  my answer and marked as solution if it really helps you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use below range query:

Here, `now/w` will give result from Monday to today and `now/w-1d` will give result from Sunday to today.

```json
POST timeindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now/w-1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```